# On showing a square matrix with at least one row and one column of all zeros has at most two eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let 
$$J=
\begin{pmatrix}0 & \vec 0_m^T & \vec 0_n^T\\
\vec0_m & A & B\\
\vec0_n & C & D
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Here we consider that $\dim{A}$, $\dim{B}$, $\dim{C}$ and $\dim{D}$ are all at least but not limited to $1$ and we need $A$ to be an $m\times m$ matrix, $D$ to be an $n\times n$ matrix, and $B$ and $C$ to be $m\times n$ and $n\times m,$ respectively. Also, $A, B, C$ and $D$ are non-zero. This means that $J$ is at least a $3\times 3$ matrix, but always square.

Upon doing some symbolic computation with Maple, whereby I keep the overall size of $J$ to be $n \times n$, I varied $A, B, C$ and $D$ to be differing sizes.

For example
Let 
$$J = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \vec0_m & \vec0_n & \vec0_n\\
\vec0_m & A & B & B\\
\vec0_n & C & D & D\\
\vec0_n & C & D & D\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

In all cases, when I compute the eigenvalues, up to $J$ being a $12 \times 12$ matrix, I always get a list of $0$'s and then $2$ eigenvalues, this assumes for A and D there is $1$ eigenvalue only.  Though I suppose the result will be that the total number of eigenvalues is a multiple of the number of eigenvalues in each matrix?

I have searched through google to see why this is the case and I have not found a reason. I was hoping it would be a theorem or something.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks to Cameron Buie for the correction suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly false with
$$
J=\left(\begin{array}{c|c|cc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\hline
0 &1&0&0\\\hline
0 &0&2&0\\
0 &0&0&3
\end{array}\right),
$$
for example.

---

**Addendum**: even with the condition $A,B,C,D$ nonzero, the result is still false, as demonstrated by
$$
J=\left(\begin{array}{c|c|cc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\hline
0 &1&10^{-10}&10^{-10}\\\hline
0 &10^{-10}&2&10^{-10}\\
0 &10^{-10}&10^{-10}&3
\end{array}\right),
$$
where $10^{-20}$ is just some extremely small numbers so it won't perturb the eigenvalues by much.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me, I realised I left a bit out saying that A, B, C and D are non zero. And in my example, D cannot be 2 and 3 at the same time.

Comment: Nearby matrices have nearby eigenvalues, so just choose extremely tiny entries to fill the zeros in $A,B,C,D$.

Comment: I see what you are saying, however, why are you using a 2 and a 3, when they are both taking the place of D. They need to both be 2 or both be 3. Is that correct? If so, then there are only two distinct non-zero eigenvalues up to some multiplicity.

Comment: No, $D=\begin{pmatrix}2&10^{-10}\\10^{-10}&3\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I see that you were using the original example of the matrix. So if we extend to a larger size, say to my second matrix, would we then obtain the same number of distinct eigenvalues up to some multiplicity?

Answer (score 0):

An easy counterexample in the $n=3$ case is $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$ Similarly, in the case $n=4$ the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\0 & 1 & 2 & 2\\0 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$ provides a counterexample.

---

Part of your (and our) confusion may be that you seem to be equivocating, here. On the one hand, you say that $A,B,C,D$ are supposed to be matrices, so in order for $J$ to be square, we need $A$ to be an $m\times m$ matrix, $D$ to be an $n\times n$ matrix, and $B$ and $C$ to be $m\times n$ and $n\times m,$ respectively. Then letting $\vec 0_m$ and $\vec 0_n$ indicate the $n$-entry column vector with all zeroes, it seems like you want to express the block form $$J=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \vec 0_m^T & \vec 0_n^T\\\vec0_m & A & B\\\vec0_n & C & D\end{pmatrix}.$$

On the other hand, in your second example, it seems that you want $D$ to be a non-zero entry occurring in four places of a $4\times 4$ matrix, or perhaps intended to impose the additional constraint that each of $A,B,C,D$ has all entries equal. Please clarify, so we may better answer your question.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean.

Comment: If so, then there is no need to write $B,C,$ or $D$ multiple times. All we're doing is altering the values of $m$ and/or $n.$ The block structure remains the same. When you do write $C$ twice, for instance, you're effectively considering the original form, but with the special case that $C$ has an even number of rows, say $2k,$ and that for all $1\le i\le k,$ row $i$ and row $i+k$ are identical.

Comment: Similarly, you're adding an additional condition about the columns of $B$ to your original example, and about both the rows and columns of $D$ to your original example.

Comment: In other words, your second example is simply a restrictive special case of the first.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix has at most two different nonzero rows. Therefore its rank is $≤2$. This means that there are at most two nonzero eigenvalues.